# CSS is not loading in Mozilla/Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have created one web page with static content. My styles are loaded in Internet Explorer but not loaded in Safari and Mozilla.

**CSS reference link in the HTML is:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
```

**CSS is:**

```
.linkText{
font-family : Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 9 pt;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
color: #015C28;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

code:

```
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="25%"> <a href="../serverName/xxxxxx.html">
<strong class="linkText"><b>Winback Offers</b></strong></a></td>
```

Please advise me.

Comment: Might be due to the fact that you're styling a 'strong' tag. Try to use `<span>` instead.

Comment: The web developer's mantra: "If it works in IE but not other browsers, your markup is wrong."

Comment: @poepje strong tag is a legit tag and SHOULD be used to make things strong! This is what semantic markup is all about!

Comment: Aside from making it strong I mean. You can use both <span> and <strong> tags for the same text. Also, you are now using both <b> and <strong> tags, that seems a little unneccesary to me? (they have the same function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reduce the amount of tags to this:

```
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="25%"> 
  <a href="../serverName/xxxxxx.html" class="linkText">
     Winback Offers
  </a>
</td>
```

Then correct the typos in your CSS to this:

```
.linkText{
  font-family : Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #015C28;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

You did

- use two `#` in front of the color code
- use a space between the `9` and its unit `pt`

The your output will look like the one in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G6e8f/1/).

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the class to the a tag. Like `<a class="linkText" href=""></a>`.

Also I have seen that the css color added is incorrect. Like `##015C28`. There are 2 hashes present.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from having inline styles using HTML attributes (that is a horrible idea)…

- First of all, no space between 9 and 'pt in' `font-size: 9 pt;`
- Second, remove one hash in `color: ##015C28;`

**P.S.** Why do you have `<b>` within `<strong>`??? It's like saying to a browser "I want the boldest MF text you can give me". Not good, man, not good.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given your HTML the Class...

The HTML should be..

```
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="25%" class="linkText"> <a href="../serverName/xxxxxx.html">Winback Offers</a>
```

Comment: There is a class on <strong>

Answer (score 1):

this is because you give class inside the anchor tag that is not valid
try this and this will work

```
<style type="text/css">
.linkText a{
    font-family : Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 9 pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #015C28;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="25%">
<span class="linkText">
    <a href="../serverName/xxxxxx.html">Winback Offers</a>
</span>
</td>
```